# Qt Creator - Qt Quick: Line: 1: Qt Quick emulation layer crashed

Tags: python, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, pyside2

I am new to Qt Creator and I was trying to make a Qt Quick application I had an issue. In the design tab it refuses to render the window raising the error `Line: 1: Qt Quick emulation layer crashed` I uninstalled the qt creator and reinstalled it again and had the same issue even installing an older version raises the same error. I tried the solution mentioned here [Solution](https://www.qt.io/blog/2015/02/24/qt-5-4-1-released#comment-1195025) by going to the Options dialog => Qt Quick => Qt Quick Designer => QML Emulation Layer and disabling the checkbox "Always use the QML emulation layer prived by Qt Creator" but this also didn't solve the issue